# Bulk Copy Utility for Sybase IQ

Tags: java, database, sybase, bcp, sap-iq

I am developing an application in java. In my application I have to bulk copy some data to SybaseIQ database. For this I am not able to find out the Bulk Utility "**iq_bcp**".

Can anyone tell me where can I get **standalone bulk-copy utility for SybaseIQ**.

I have installed SybaseIQ-15 in my machine but I am not able to find the iq_bcp utility in installed directory.

**P.S** : Currently I am working in Windows OS but I need this utility for Linux also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iq_bcp` is no longer supported with IQ 15.x

use `load table..using client file` instead.

More information can be found in the [Sybase IQ Administration Guide Volume 1: Data Import and Export.](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1540/doc/html/san1288042629439.html)

To do this using dbisql, you will run dbisql in *batch* mode.  This can be done in the following ways:

1. Create a file with the commands you wish to execute, and run dbisql inputting that file:

   ```
   dbisql -host yourhost -port 1234 -c "uid=dba;pwd=password" C:\Path\to\your\file.dat
   ```
2. Run dbisql, with commands you wish to run following the connection string:

   ```
   dbisql -host yourhost -port 1234 -c "uid=dba;pwd=password" "load table..using..."
   ```

Comment: I checked for utility also in the installation directory but I am not able to locate this too. Before which version does iq_bcp was supported?

Comment: iq_bcp was supported in 12.x versions.  Are you sure you don't want to use the Open Client software to load your data store? Check into the Open Client Server/ Open Client SDK.  It may have what you are looking for.

Comment: also, `load table` is not a seperate utility.  The command can be issued through `dbisql`, `dbisqlc`, or `isql`.  These utilities support batch, or scripted operations, so this may also accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Michael, I am able to load the data using load command.
Here is the sample command : 

load table TEST_TABLE(COL1 '^$', COL2 '^$') using client file 'D:\\TEST_TABLE.dat' FORMAT ASCII QUOTES OFF ESCAPES OFF BYTE ORDER LOW MESSAGE LOG 'D:\\1.LOG' ROW LOG 'd:\\1R.LOG'

how can I execute this via command prompt without opening dbisql?

Comment: Create a file with the commands you wish to execute.  From the command line `dbisql -host YOURHOST -port 1234 -c "uid=dba;pwd=password" C:\Path\to\your\file.dat`